# react-images-upload with defaults

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with react-images-upload on a react app and was wondering if anyone had a few examples of using a default image with their uploads. I see on the docs it says defaultImages and has it as an array. Has anyone ever made a component that would take an image that it has on state and put it as the default, but then have it possibility be updated after an image upload?

I'm looking for a quick and easy example out there but can't find one.

Comment: hi, have you found any example of this?